# Issues with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have been having permission issues with `pip`.

I cannot run `pip3 -V` or `pip3.5 -V`. It gives me the following error:

> AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

However, `pip -V` run fines. Then again `pip --user <package-name>` gives the same error.

I also tried doing the same thing with Anaconda installation, but I have the same issue.

I am new to python so I may be doing something trivially wrong.

Relevant details:

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04
2. Python versions: 2.7, 3, 3.5, 3.6 through Anaconda

I have updated `setuptools` and `pip`.

Relevant links that provided me some insight but the solution did not work:

1. [pip GitHub 1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4216)
2. [pip GitHub 2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4935)

Error when issuing pip3 -V

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 33,
>   in vendored
>       **import**(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0) ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line
>   7, in 
>       from pip import main   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 13, in
>   
>       from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from pip._vendor.six import iteritems   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 75,
>   in 
>       vendored("pkg_resources")   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 36,
>   in vendored
>       **import**(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)   File "", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 634, in
>   _load_backward_compatible   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2927, in    File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2913, in _call_aside   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 956, in subscribe   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2952, in    File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2515, in activate   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2097, in declare_namespace   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2047, in _handle_ns   File
>   "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path AttributeError: '_NamespacePath'
>   object has no attribute 'sort'

Please feel free to ask more details.

Comment: Notes: I can run `sudo pip3 -V`. However, documentation says I should NOT be using `sudo`, I should rather be using `pip3 install --user <package>`

Comment: One thing I am not able to understand is why are all versions of `pip`referring to `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/init.py"`. I would imagine Python3 referring to some python3 directories rather than python2.7. Also, I created a local directory and compiled python3.6 from source and installed in a local directory (not /usr/local/bin). The pip command in the new installation also refers to the same python2.7 directory! Maybe this is how it should be, but really confused and wondering if my configuration is wrong.

Comment: Note: So I checked the contents of `pip3` (in the personal directory installation from source) and it has a line from pip import main. Now when I run `pip3 -V` it refers to an error coming from `/usr/lib/python2.7...`. Something tells me this is an issue. I guess it should be getting the packages from the local folder installation and be agnostic to what is installed in my system!

Comment: Try using `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3`?  Does that get you anything?  Also, does your Anaconda have a functioning `pip` at all?  IIRC they lobotomized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. On Linux you can do `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Turns out my PYTHONPATH had several locations to different Python distributions from other packages I had installed. I removed them and the issue is resolved. The environment variable was also modified in my `.bashrc` file and I removed those.